# Block remote desktop connection outside network

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop

Is it possible to block, with Windows settings only (no firewall), Remote Desktop connections coming outside our network and allow connections only for PCs in private LAN?

Comment: I don't think there's any built-in way to do that specifically, as the Windows firewall was designed for that purpose.  Why can't you use the firewall?

Comment: RDP's security is user-centric, not connection-centric, so any pc that can contact the workstation can establish an RDP connection. it may not allow the user to login, but it will connect. as such, if you want to prevent externals from accessing your system at all, you need to use networking tools like firewalls. Note that if you have a Firewall/NAT router, RDP is most likely already blocked for outsiders, unless you have allowed connections to tcp\3389 through your firewall and nat.

Comment: RDP port is configurable, so blocking 3389 will only block the default port

Comment: You could set, using group policy, the list of allowed uses to only domain computers. That would, assuming you have no laptops outside the local network, effectively prevent outside devices from authenticating.  Exceptions could, of course, be made for designated users or PC's.

Answer (score 1):

If you're enforcing network level authentication (only) for RDP, you can leave the port open and the user will not be able to establish a session without authenticating first.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Level_Authentication

Comment: It might be a correct answer, but you're not really explaining how the OP should use Network Level Authentication. I would recommend you to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Any router sold to the general public for home use **should already be configured to NOT forward any requests on port 3389** (and 3388, and most other ports) from the internet to computers on your local network.

So it *should* just ignore (and maybe log) anyone attempting to RDP into one of your devices from the outside world.

Look at your router's port forwarding settings to confirm (If you need help, search for tutorials on how to *enable* RDP from outside, which is what most people search for).